# How to sandbox Bash shell to affect only current directory?

Tags: bash

I heavily use Bash to automate my work. Hence I often [re]write long chunks of code right in the prompt. Is there a way to make commands in any way affect only files from current directory? So in case I'll write something like `rm -r /home/user/ tmp/pwd` it won't get to all user's files while I'm in `/home/user/tmp/pwd`. AFAIU `chroot` is not an option here.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea why you posted this and I'm flagging the comment, @saleemrashid1. I hope you either understand why you shouldn't post such commands or get banned.

Comment: I clearly didn't explain myself well enough and was simply a modification (in possible bad taste) of the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a user who has access to only this directory:

```
 useradd -d "`pwd`" -s /bin/bash -c "Temporary" temporary
 passwd temporary
 su temporary
```

Do whatever you want with this user. The current directory is his home directory, he can't destroy anything outside of it. Once you're done, exit the su with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, then do:

```
userdel temporary
```

You could make shortcut commands for this in your `.bashrc` file